# New To Salesforce - What Are These Two Validation Rules Saying/Meaning?

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I am trying to determine what the following validation rules are saying or mean. Can you please help?

**VALIDATION RULE 1**

IF(AND( Amount > 100000,ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")),NOT(AND(Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c, ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved"))),IF(ISBLANK(Comm_Type__c),NOT(AND(Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c, ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved"))),FALSE) 
)

**VALIDATION RULE 2**

AND (ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed & Booked"), (Credit_Approved_Amount__c < Amount || Credit_Expiration_Date__c < TODAY () || ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Waiting for More Info") || ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Declined") || LEN(Account.GP_Customer_Id__c) = 0 || ISBLANK(Credit_Approved_Amount__c) || ISBLANK( Credit_Expiration_Date__c ) || ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c , "") ))

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First formula:**

There are a few different operators here. I'll start from the top of the first formula and work my way down. The first formula starts with an IF function, which has three parameters. Call them A, B, C. In this case, A is the block that starts with AND, B starts with NOT, and C starts with IF. IF evaluates the initial condition (A), and returns B if (A == true), or C if (A == false). 
Another operator that appears is AND. AND returns true if **all** of its conditions are true.

It sounds complicated, it's helpful to break compound formulas like these up into pieces. Here is the formula again with indentations and annotations to help explain (comments marked by ###):

The first formula with notes:

```
IF(                                                       ### our initial IF which 
                                                              will evaluate A, and 
                                                              return B if true, 
                                                              C if false
    AND(                                                  ### this is A. 
        Amount > 100000,
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")
    ),
    NOT(                                                  ### this is B.
        AND(
            Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,
            TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c, 
            ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved")
        )
    ),
    IF(                                                   ### this is C
        ISBLANK(Comm_Type__c),                            ### this is CA
        NOT(                                              ### this is CB
            AND(
                Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,
                TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c, 
                ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved")
            )
        )
        ,
        FALSE                                             ### this is CC
    ) 
)
```

So since A is using an AND operator, for A to be true, Amount must be greater than 100000 and StageName must be 'Closed Won.' If only one is true and the other is false, A will be false.

So let's say A is true, then we return B. To determine the value of B, you'll see that there is another AND, wrapped with a NOT. Start with the inner AND - if all three of these statements are true (Amount less than or equal to the value of the field Credit_Approved_Amount__c, Credit_Expiration_Date__c earlier than today, Credit_Status__c is 'Approved'), then the AND will return true. Otherwise, return false. The NOT that wraps this AND means that whatever the AND operator returns, the NOT returns the opposite. So if all three of these statements are true, the AND will return true, but the NOT will return false.

If A is false, then we return C. C begins with another IF. Remember that the IF operator evaluates its first parameter (CA), and returns its second parameter (CB) if true, the third (CC) if false. In this case, you'll see that CB matches our inner formula B exactly, which I explained above. So if CA is true (Comm_Type__c is blank), CB is returned. Otherwise, CC is returned, which is just a nice clean 'false' in this case.

**Second formula:**

The second formula is actually much simpler. The || operator performs the same function as OR, meaning that it returns true if **any** of its component statements are true. For example, if you had OR(A, B, C, D) and A B and C were false, but D was true, then the whole OR would return true. For this second forumla, if StageName is 'Closed & Booked' and **ANY** one or more of the following statements are true, then the whole formula will return true.

```
AND (
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed & Booked"),
    (
        Credit_Approved_Amount__c < Amount 
        || 
        Credit_Expiration_Date__c < TODAY () 
        || 
        ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Waiting for More Info") 
        || 
        ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Declined") 
        || 
        LEN(Account.GP_Customer_Id__c) = 0 
        || 
        ISBLANK(Credit_Approved_Amount__c) 
        || 
        ISBLANK( Credit_Expiration_Date__c ) 
        || 
        ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c , "") 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

> VALIDATION RULE 1
>
> IF(AND( Amount > 100000,ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed
>   Won")),NOT(AND(Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,TODAY()<=
>   Credit_Expiration_Date__c, ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c,
>   "Approved"))),IF(ISBLANK(Comm_Type__c),NOT(AND(Amount<=
>   Credit_Approved_Amount__c,TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c,
>   ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved"))),FALSE) )

**IF** 
Amount is greater than 100,000 and the Stage Name picklist is Closed Won

**THEN** check if Amount is less than or equal to the Credit Approved Amount and Today's date is less than or equal to the Credit Expiration date and the Credit Status picklist is Approved and if this is true return false and if false return true (this is the NOT on the start of this)

**OTHERWISE** if the check on Amount is greater than 100,000 and the Stage Name picklist is Closed Won is false

**THEN** **IF** check is Comm Type Blank and if it is

**THEN** check if Amount is less than or equal to the Credit Approved Amount and Today's date is less than or equal to the Credit Expiration Date and the Credit Status Picklist value is Approved and if False return True and if True return False.

(Note that you are looking for a true value to trigger the validation rule, you have to try and think about that backwards I find, you are writing an exception catcher so you want your formula to be true when someone is doing something they shouldn't.

Also I find it easier if you break these things down into a more readable format like

```
IF(
 AND( 
  Amount > 100000,ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")),
   NOT(
    AND(
     Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c, ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved"))),
   IF(ISBLANK(Comm_Type__c),
    NOT(
     AND(
      Amount<= Credit_Approved_Amount__c,TODAY()<= Credit_Expiration_Date__c, ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c, "Approved"))),
FALSE)
)
```

> VALIDATION RULE 2
>
> AND (ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed & Booked"),
>   (Credit_Approved_Amount__c < Amount || Credit_Expiration_Date__c <
>   TODAY () || ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Waiting for More Info") ||
>   ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Declined") ||
>   LEN(Account.GP_Customer_Id__c) = 0 ||
>   ISBLANK(Credit_Approved_Amount__c) || ISBLANK(
>   Credit_Expiration_Date__c ) || ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c , "") ))

This one is a lot more straight forward, basically it's saying If the Stage Name picklist is "Closed & Booked" and any of the other field values being checked below are True then the validation returns an error. 
So plain Enlgish
If Stage Name is "Closed & Booked"

**AND** (think of this as Stage Name must be that value and all of the rest of these values only need one to be true for the validation to fire)
Credit Approved Amount is less that Amount

**OR** Credit Expiration Date is less than Today

**OR** Credit Status picklist is "Waiting for More Info" **OR** "Declined"

**OR** The Length of GP Customer ID on Account object is 0

**OR** Credit Approved Amount is blank (might want to use ISNULL here)

**OR** Credit Expiration Date is blank

**OR** Credit Status picklist is null (set to none/unset)

**THEN** return true and fire the validation rule otherwise false and don't fire it.

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed & Booked"), 
   (Credit_Approved_Amount__c < Amount || 
   Credit_Expiration_Date__c < TODAY () || 
   ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Waiting for More Info") ||
   ISPICKVAL(Credit_Status__c, "Declined") ||
   LEN(Account.GP_Customer_Id__c) = 0 ||
   ISBLANK(Credit_Approved_Amount__c) || 
   ISBLANK( Credit_Expiration_Date__c ) || 
   ISPICKVAL( Credit_Status__c , "") )
)
```

Comment: Ok so for our order of stages we go from Closed Won to Closed & Booked and we have a case where something gets to Closed Won and then when we change it to Closed & Booked we are getting an error. And I am trying to determine what that is. And my guess is that if it gets to closed won and is an opportunity that is under 100,000 and comm type is not blank then it can save at Closed Won. And from there when changing to Closed and Booked it is looking for those fields for credit to be complete. And since they are not complete then it triggers a "true" response thus generating an error. Correct?

Comment: @RachelLinder yep I'd say it's the second validation that's acting as a catch all in that criteria. You could try adding other conditionals in there to avoid this but I'd instead look at simplifying the current validation rules and adding another perhaps for the large number of OR checks in the second validation rule.

Comment: I met with our operations director and created an excel document that shows the scenarios we are trying to cover when we move from Opportunity Stage "Commit" to Opportunity Stage "Closed Won" OR Opportunity Stage "Closed & Booked" Is there a way I can add an image here to show this?

Comment: Upload it to imgur.com and post the link might work.

Comment: Ok I am giving this a try :). The link is: http://imgur.com/tjTlrqC

Comment: Can see it, what's the question though? Does your examples in the image meet the specs above? Or are you looking for validation rules to cover those scenarios?

Comment: Hi Shane, I am trying to write one validation rule to cover all those scenarios. Do you think one scenario would be more difficult to maintain? If so then I could just do individual validation rules. Again this should kick in (so to speak) whenever anyone moves an opportunity from any of the prior stages of Prospecting, Pipeline, Upside, Commit to either Closed Won or Closed & Booked.

Comment: Remember you can only trigger one particular error message per validation rule, if you wanted more complex messaging you'd need to use apex.

You could achieve all of it in one validation rule but you can't have a different message for each field, you'd need to make your error message point out the fields in question so like a catch all. Even if Status, Amount were populated and Expiration Date wasn't your error would still need to indicate all 3 fields.

Comment: For the "whenever anyone moves an opportunity from any of the prior stages of .... to the Closed statuses" you'd look at using ISCHANGED or PRIORVALUE functions.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm